# LNK2005 LNK1169 errors c++ bank account code

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm trying to build a Bank Account code which isn't complete yet. While I'm trying first parts I'm gonna write several accounts into a Bank Account text file. And then read from that text file and create Account objects. This is how my teacher exactly wants, firstly i can not change the method you should know that. While i'm trying to write and read the file and set the parameters to my object i get two errors which i don't understand. I checked the other questions but my code knowledge is too little. I can't read someone else's code so i can't solve my codes problem from reading it, it's too complicated for me. My Code:

BankAccount.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef BankAccount_h
#define BankAccount_h


#include <string>

using namespace std; 

class BankAccount
{
public:
    int static countobj;
    int userID;
    string userName;
    string userSurname;
    int balance;
    BankAccount(int, string, string, int);
    BankAccount()
    {

    }
    void openFile();
    void openAccount();
    void readAccount();
    void setParameter(int, string, string, int);
    void displayAccount();
    int depositMoney();
    int withdrawMoney();
    void displayFullAccount();
}Account[5];

#endif
```

BankAccount.cpp

```
#include "BankAccount.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int BankAccount::countobj = 0;

void BankAccount::openFile()
{
    string line;
    ofstream bankaccount;
    bankaccount.open("BankAccount.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, line);
        bankaccount << line << endl;
    }
    bankaccount.close();
}

void BankAccount::readAccount()
{
    ifstream read("BankAccount.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while (read >> userID >> userName >> userSurname >> balance)
    {
        Account[i].userID = userID;
        Account[i].userName = userName;
        Account[i].userSurname = userSurname;
        Account[i].balance = balance;
    }
    countobj = i;
    read.close();
}

void BankAccount::setParameter(int id, string name, string sname, int b)
{
    id = userID;
    name = userName;
    sname = userSurname;
    b = balance;
}

void BankAccount::displayFullAccount()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < countobj; i++)
    {
        cout << Account[i].userID << " " << Account[i].userName << " " << Account[i].userSurname << " " << Account[i].balance << endl;
    }
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "BankAccount.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BankAccount acc;
    acc.openFile();
    acc.readAccount();
    acc.displayFullAccount();
}
```

I get these errors:

> Error LNK2005 "public: static int BankAccount::countobj"
>   (?countobj@BankAccount@@2HA) already defined in BankAccount.obj
>
> Error LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found

couldn't fix it. How can i fix it?

Comment: The error message suggests that you also defined `BankAccount::countobj` in another source file that you haven't shown here, in addition to `BankAccount.cpp`. The linker error message would mention the name of that file, but you omitted that part of the message, too.

Comment: i guess it says it's in Source.cpp which is not.

Comment: If I had to guess: the actual code you are compiling is different from the code you show. In it, `int BankAccount::countobj = 0;` line (or similar) is in the header file, and so it ends up included in more than one source file.

Comment: Actually, I expect a linker error about `Account` variable. That one is definitely defined in the header, and so you end up with multiple definitions, one in each source file that includes that header.